# PHPExcel with remote Host Fatal Error

Tags: php, phpexcel

PHPExcel - Excel5 works on XAMPP but not on remote host im getting this

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Could not
>   open NACHA.xls for reading! File does not exist, or it is not
>   readable.' in
>   /home/runway/public_html/commissions/PHPExcel/Classes/PHPExcel/Shared/OLERead.php:79

```
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
    ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);
    define('EOL',(PHP_SAPI == 'cli') ? PHP_EOL : '<br />');
    date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
    echo date('H:i:s') , " Load from Excel5 template" , EOL;
    $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel5');
    $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load("NACHA.xls");

  <-----i just didnt include the Mysql fetchRow, connectivity ect here.. 


    $baseRow = 3;
    foreach($data as $r => $dataRow) {
       $row = $baseRow + $r;
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->insertNewRowBefore($row,1);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A'.$row, $r+1)
                      ->setCellValue('B'.$row, $dataRow['EMAIL ADDRESS'])
                      ->setCellValue('C'.$row, $dataRow['AMOUNT']);
     }
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->removeRow($baseRow-1,1);
echo date('H:i:s') , " Write to Excel5 format" , EOL;
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');
$objWriter->save(str_replace('.php', '.xls', __FILE__));
echo date('H:i:s') , " File written to " , str_replace('.php', '.xls', 
pathinfo(__FILE__, PATHINFO_BASENAME)) , EOL;

 // Echo memory peak usage
 echo date('H:i:s') , " Peak memory usage: " , (memory_get_peak_usage(true) / 1024 /   
 1024) , " MB" , EOL;
 // Echo done
echo date('H:i:s') , " Done writing file" , EOL;
echo 'File has been created in ' , getcwd() , EOL;
echo '<br/>';
echo "<a href=http://mcommission.com/commissions/PHPExcel/Tests/NACHA.xls>" . "<b>CONVERT</b></a>";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Error is self explanatory**.

Check whether the file really exist. 

If it does, giving it permission using `chmod 777` will resolve the issue.

Comment: Ill already change the permission of PHPExcel Folder but im still getting the same error

Comment: @ArkNet, I answered your question first and you selected my answer, another guy comes and answers the same and you select his answer ? lol what are you ?

Answer (score 0):

Check whether the file "NACHA.xls" really exist not the PHPExcel folder
If it does, giving it permission using chmod 777 will resolve the issue.

Comment: I used this library and be careful at the file permissions